# unable to Get json key value

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have a python code below to get the json key value , but i am getting below.

```
import json
import datetime
import dateutil
import time
import os

secret = os.system("aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id stage_secret --query SecretString --output text")
print(secret)
data = (secret["username"])
print(data)
```

Output of `secret` is `{"username":"user1","password":"psswd@123"}`

i wanted to extract the value of `username` and `password` and store it in a variable, but i am getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    data = (secret["username"])
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Please help to achieve the same

```
Python Version Python 2.7.5
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using boto3 library? Or Python3?

Comment: `os.system()` returns exit code as far as I know, which is a int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Output of secret is ...

No it isn't. If you refer to the `os.system()` docs, the result is the exit code of the command, which is an int.

If you want to capture output, use `subprocess` module

```
import subprocess
import json

secret_id = "stage_secret"  # do NOT store this in your source code 
output_mode = "text"
output = subprocess.check_output(["aws", "secretsmanager" , "get-secret-value", "--secret-id", secret_id, "--query", "SecretString", "--output", output_mode])

data = json.loads(output.strip())
print(data['username'])
```

However, you should really [consider using `boto3`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager.html)

Comment: Thank you OneCricketeer , let me try the subprocess option , i think this should work. I will also look at having the boto3 module.